# How to enable CORS in Chrome. Preflight 405 error

Tags: json, wcf, google-chrome, aurelia

I have a wcf restful service that I need to get working in Chrome. I've read around and added all sorts of headers, etc but nothing is working. The POST works fine in IE, but when I get to Chrome, I get a 405 error on the OPTIONS request telling me that the method is not allowed. I've read where some people have added stuff to their global.asax file, but really don't feel like that should be necessary. I don't even have a global asax file and creating one just for the sole purpose of getting to work in chrome for development *only* seems crazy.

I'm using Aurelia's HTTP-Client library which uses just a simple XMLHttpRequest. Here's how it's configured:

```
this.Client = new HttpClient()
            .configure(x => {
                x.withBaseUrl("http://localhost/MyServices/MyService.svc/")

            });
```

And I'm making the call like so:

```
this.Client.post("PostData/" + name,
            {
                version: 1
            })
            .then(resp => {
                console.log(resp);
            })
```

Here are the headers that I have added in my WCF Restful service WebConfig:

```
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />

<!-- Not sure if these even do anything -->
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type, Accept, X-Requested-With" />
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="OPTIONS, GET, POST" />
```

Then in my service itself:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "/PostData/{name}", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
Data myData(byte id, string name);
```

Like I said above, it works fine in IE, but chrome gives me a preflight error. Here's a snippet of the fiddler response:

```
HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed

Entity
Content-Length: 1565
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

Security
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Accept, X-Requested-With
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: OPTIONS, GET, POST
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Allow: POST
```

I also find that if I add `x.withHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8")` to my Http-Client configuration, Chrome doesn't even do a GET request. It throws the error.

To sum it all up, I can do GET requests but not POST requests in Chrome. How do I fix it?